# Loading error pyspark from postgres: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o37.load.: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver

Tags: postgresql, pyspark

I want to read data from PostgreSQL database using pyspark. I use windows and run code in jupyter notebook. This is my code:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
.appName("testApp") \
.config("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "C:/Users/haase/postgresql-42.6.0.jar") \
.getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://address:port/data") \
.option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver").option("dbtable", "ts_kv") \
.option("user", "data").option("password", "data").load()
```

Received error message:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o61.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverRegistry$.register(DriverRegistry.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.$anonfun$driverClass$1(JDBCOptions.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.$anonfun$driverClass$1$adapted(JDBCOptions.scala:101)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:210)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:171)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
```

I tried also adding `.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath","C:/Users/haase/postgresql-42.6.0.jar")`, updating `SPARK_CONF_DIR` system variable to `SPARK_CONF_DIR=C:\Users\haase\postgresql-42.6.0.jar` but neither helped. Any idea what am I doing wrong?